# Can SQL Server be configured to backup to a network share through a separate NIC?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, network

We're in the process having our SQL Server instances backup to a network share, but our network admins want to try and divert the bandwidth from the backups through a different network segment. I was curious if it were possible to configure SQL Server to run all backups through a secondary NIC?

Most of our servers are virtualized (so presenting the NIC isn't a problem) and we're running on SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012, & 2014 throughout our infrastructure.

Comment: You could use a unique name for the target computer that is only visible over the alternate NIC.  If the primary Nic is 192.168.0/24 and the alternate is 192.168.1/24 then the share could have an alternate ip of 192.168.1.x - then you'd backup to \\192.168.1.x\sharename

Comment: @MaxVernon I'll work with my sysadmin to get that configured and get back with the results. 
That seems like it should work. :)

Comment: [Joe Chang](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/joe_chang/archive/2008/11/22/dedicated-network-adapter-s-for-transferring-sql-backups-to-the-tape-archival-system.aspx) talks about Dedicated Network Adapter(s) for transferring SQL backups to the tape archival system. You should also follow the same though. @MaxVernon is right on spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see the Microsoft whitepaper [A Technical Case Study: Fast and Reliable Backup and Restore of Multi-Terabyte Database Over the Network (DOC)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/9/4/d948f981-926e-40fa-a026-5bfcf076d9b9/Technical%20Case%20Study-Backup%20VLDB%20Over%20Network_Final.docx). On page 15, they explain how to separate out the backup targets onto multiple subnets and volumes.